# Delay emails sent and received through IMAP

Tags: windows, outlook, imap

I want to put emails the user receives in a sort of "review status" in my app and let users choose manually if they want them to be let through.

For this I need to filter network traffic to withhold emails receivef with the IMAP protocol from Outlook and send them some time afterward. And to the same for emails being sent.

Would this be possible to do on Outlook on Windows 7/8? Or would I be unable to make Outlook receive the mailing after I filter it out?

Comment: I think you might do well to read either the IMAP specification (called RFC3501) or the Outlook plugin documentation, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for foltering emails.

Instead, you may consider handling the new email programmatically in the code handling the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. For example, you may develop a VBA macro for doing any customizations in Outlook programmatically. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information.